# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' error when running pipenv

Tags: python, module, pip, pipenv

I am trying to use a `requests` module. However, when importing `requests`, I get an error. I have tried reinstalling it on `pipenv`, and changed the Python interpreter to that of the virtual environment. I'm currently using Python 3.10.5 on Windows.

After installing the module in the terminal:

`pipenv install requests`

I get the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

I checked the Pipfile, and the module is there:

`[packages] requests = "*"`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried **pip install requests** ?

Comment: Yes, but it's still giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried pip install requests ?

Update: I uninstalled pipenv, and then installed pip. That fixed the issue!